# Change white background during load page in 2021

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, dark-mode

Look at gif. Enabled [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh) extension. When the page loading, blink white screen. Is there any possible to change it to dark? All solutions that I found didn't work today.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension that protects against this:
[WhiteSlash - White background flash fix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whiteslash-white-backgrou/koiiicglkbcomcplnggedapdhafigbje?hl=en).

> WhiteSlash is a fix for the white flash in chrome that is shown whenever a link is clicked or a new tab is opened before the page fully loads. Protect your eyes and use this extension combined with Dark Reader.

Comment: Doesn't work, like and other users

Comment: It doesn't work at all, or is your case not handled by it? Are you using [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, with Dark Reader. White screen during load pages no fix.

Comment: Is the desktop theme set to a dark theme? See [this comment](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/issues/1219#issuecomment-731631990).

Comment: What are javascripts need to block with uBlock Origin?